# How to implement tap-to-focus, tap-to-set-exposure

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I'm building this code for future learning and fun. It supposed to open the camera and enable the touch focus. It works in the rear-facing camera, but nothing happens when i flip it to the front camera. I have searched alot, but could not find any code fix to that problem. Could anyone please show me step by step with code how to make touch focus also work in the front camera view?

Down below is the focus function:

```
- (void) focus:(CGPoint) aPoint{



    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] &&
       [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        double screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        double screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        double focus_x = aPoint.x/screenWidth;
        double focus_y = aPoint.y/screenHeight;
        if([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scanViewController:didTapToFocusOnPoint:)]) {
                [self.delegate scanViewController:self didTapToFocusOnPoint:aPoint];
            }
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(focus_x,focus_y)];
            [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]){
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

The whole source can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/Alex04/6976945

**UPDATE:**

```
if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported])
{
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
    [device setExposurePointOfInterest:aPoint];
    if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure])
    {
        [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
    }
    [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the front-facing camera supports tap-to-focus on any iPhone.  You can check for support by checking the [`focusPointOfInterestSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/focusPointOfInterestSupported) property of the `AVCaptureDevice`.

If you want to implement tap-for-exposure, check the device's [`exposurePointOfInterestSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/exposurePointOfInterestSupported) property.  If the device supports the feature, set the [`exposurePointOfInterest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/exposurePointOfInterest) property to use it.

Comment: I want this to mimic the real iphone camera. Where when you touch any place while using front camera it change the light kind of.. but dont know how to do that too

Comment: Could you please provide code step by step how to implant inside the source that i have linked to? but thanks for telling me the right name, becouse i did not know the name of it

Comment: You'll have to try to implement it yourself. It should be similar to the code you already have.